# how to understand the remap tag when extracting images from ROS.bag file?

Tags: image, ros

What I'd like to do is to extract images from ROS .bag file and then to make a mp4 video from it.
Following this link: https://www.pianshen.com/article/9945320163/ and the ros wiki, I think I roughly understand the procedure to extract images from a give .bag file. Yet, I encountered a problem while trying to figure out the remap tag. My .bag file has many topics and I do not know how to get the interested topics. During the trials and errors process, I always get the following message:

`[ERROR] [1638797416.552069577]: Client [/extract] wants topic /pred/pred_tra_rviz to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743], but our version has [visualization_msgs/MarkerArray/d155b9ce5188fbaf89745847fd5882d7]. Dropping connection.`
Any comments are greatly appreciated.
EDIT: the launch file looks like this:

```
<launch>
      <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" required="true" args="/opt/ros/melodic/share/image_view/myBag.bag"/>
      <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" required="true" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
      <remap from="image" to="/prediction/predicted_trajectories_rviz"/>
    </node>
    </launch>
```

I do not know how to handle the type mismatch message. What I'd like to do is to extract images from ros bags, and then compress them to get a clip of mp4 videos, the same as how I play the ros bag when entering "rosbag play /path_to_my_ros_bag/" on the terminal. I inspected the launch file I used for the rosbag play command. It's like the following.

```
<launch>
  <arg name="tracked_objects_topic" default="/detected_object/objects" />
  <arg name="ego_car_state_topic" default="/current_pva" />
  <arg name="traffic_signal_topic" default="/perception/signal_response" />
  <arg name="roadmap_rviz_topic" default="/prediction/roadmap_rviz" />
  <arg name="ego_rviz_topic" default="/prediction/ego_rviz" />
  <arg name="object_rviz_topic" default="/prediction/object_rviz" />
  <arg name="rosbag" default="" />
  <arg name="interval" default="0.1" />
  <arg name="skip" default="0.0" />
  <arg name="show_box" default="true" />
  <arg name="show_ego" default="true" />
  <arg name="show_roadmap" default="true" />
  <arg name="roadmap_range" default="300" />
  <arg name="show_rviz" default="true" />

  <node pkg="prediction" type="map_client_test" name="map_client_test_node" output="screen" required="true">
    <param name="tracked_objects_topic" value="$(arg tracked_objects_topic)" />
    <param name="ego_car_state_topic" value="$(arg ego_car_state_topic)" />
    <param name="traffic_signal_topic" value="$(arg traffic_signal_topic)" />
    <param name="roadmap_rviz_topic" value="$(arg roadmap_rviz_topic)" />
    <param name="ego_rviz_topic" value="$(arg ego_rviz_topic)" />
    <param name="object_rviz_topic" value="$(arg object_rviz_topic)" />
    <param name="rosbag" value="$(arg rosbag)" />
    <param name="interval" value="$(arg interval)" />
    <param name="skip" value="$(arg skip)" />
    <param name="show_box" value="$(arg show_box)" />
    <param name="show_ego" value="$(arg show_ego)" />
    <param name="show_roadmap" value="$(arg show_roadmap)" />
    <param name="roadmap_range" value="$(arg roadmap_range)" />
  </node>

  <group if="$(arg show_rviz)">
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find prediction)/launch/rviz/map_client_test.rviz" />
  </group>

</launch>
```

Comment: What does your launch file look like? And what topic are you trying to get an image from? Because your issue is a type mismatch

Comment: From this link: http://wiki.ros.org/image_view, it mentioned that ```the image (sensor_msgs/Image), The image topic. Should be remapped to the name of the real image topic. ```. So, do I need to get the name of the real image topic by ```ros info "path_to_my_bag" ```or ```ros topics list "path_to_my_bag"?

Comment: That is correct, you need to make sure the image topic has the correct mapping. From the bag file you can use `rosbag info <bagfile_path>`. Whatever image topic is there should be used in the `<remap from="image"...` line

Comment: @BTables, thank you for your reply. I just tried `rosbag info <bagfile_path>`, yet still can not find the image topic.

Comment: `$rosbag info bagfile.bag 
path:         bagfile.bag
version:      2.0
duration:     60.0s
...
size:         1.1 GB
messages:     140887
compression:  lz4 [761/761 chunks; 82.24%]
uncompressed: 1.3 GB @ 22.5 MB/s
compressed:   1.1 GB @ 18.5 MB/s (82.24%)
types:        common/Bytes                          [992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1]
              dbw_mkz_msgs/BrakeCmd                 [071bf128b9bdc978dd5a1a6a5be08be3]
......topics:       /VehicleData_Info                          120 msgs    : rideware_msgs/VehicleData_Info

Comment: I searched through the terminal output after running `rosbag info <path_to_my_bag_file>`, and still can not find anything related to the string "image". Any comments are appreciated.